# Value e is not defined

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to have a form fill out a doc using key values and then save the form for printing later in a folder in my drive. However the script keeps giving me the error "e" is not defined. I have no idea why.

```
>function myfunction(e) {
  var docTemplate = "1pKwW-RcjaVV8xmm00hWDx1u2QxzQwaSjPJwVY2ux2nI";
  var docName = "Form"; 
  var full_name = "Form";
  function onFormSubmit(e) {}
  var Assign_To_1 = e.value[2];
  var Assign_To_2 = e.value[3];
  var Timestamp = e.values[0];
  var Date_Of_Request = e.value[1];
  var Requested_By = e.value[7];
  var Principal_Approval = e.value[5];
  var Urgency = e.value[4];
  var Building_Room_Number = e.value[10];
  var Description_of_Work_To_Be_Done = e.value[6];
  var Parts_Needed = e.value[8];
  var Parts_In_Stock = e.value[9];
  var Invoice_Number = e.value[10];
  var Completed_Signature = e.value[22];
  var Incomplete_Signature = e.value[23];
  var On_Hold_Signature = e.value[24];
  var Estimated_Hours = e.value[14];
  var Number_Of_Employees_To_Complete = e.value[18];
  var Budget = e.value[11];
  var Follow_Up = e.value[16];
  var Overtime = e.value[15];
  var copyId = DocsList.getFileById(docTemplate)
.makeCopy(docName+' for '+full_name)
.getId();
  var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);
  var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();
  copyBody.replaceText('KeyAssignedTo1',Assign_To_1);
  copyBody.replaceText('KeyAssignedTo2',Assign_To_2);
  copyBody.replaceText('KeyTimestamp',Timestamp);
  copyBody.replaceText('KeyDateOfRequest',Date_Of_Request);
  copyBody.replaceText('KeyRequestedBy',Requested_By); 
  copyBody.replaceText('KeyPrincipalApproval',Principal_Approval);
  copyBody.replaceText('KeyUrgency',Urgency);
  copyBody.replaceText('KeyBuildingRoomNumber',Building_Room_Number);
  copyBody.replaceText('KeyDescriptionofWorkToBeDone',Description_of_Work_To_Be_Done);
  copyBody.replaceText('KeyPartsNeeded', Parts_Needed);
  copyBody.replaceText('KeyPartsInStock', Parts_In_Stock);
  copyBody.replaceText('KeyInvoiceNumber', Invoice_Number);
  copyBody.replaceText('KeyCompletedSignature', Completed_Signature);
  copyBody.replaceText('KeyIncompleteSignature', Incomplete_Signature);
  copyBody.replaceText('KeyOnHoldSignature', On_Hold_Signature);
  copyBody.replaceText('KeyEstimatedHours', Estimated_Hours);
  copyBody.replaceText('KeyNumberOfEmployeesToComplete', Number_Of_Employees_To_Complete);
  copyBody.replaceText('KeyBudget', Budget);
  copyBody.replaceText('KeyFoolowUp', Follow_Up);
  copyBody.replaceText('KeyOvertime', Overtime);
  copyDoc.saveAndClose();
  var pdf = DocsList.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf");
  var doc = DocsList.getFileById(copyId);
var folders = doc.getParents();
var newFolder=DocsList.getFolder(WorkOrderForms);
doc.addToFolder(WorkOrderForms);
var docParentFolder=folders[0];
doc.removeFromFolder(docParentFolder);
   }
```

Please Help!

Comment: What programming language/framework is this?

Comment: Your function: `function myfunction() {` isn't terminated before the `onFormSubmit` function begins.  That would create an error.

Comment: I am sorry I feel like I am pushing my luck here. I have a folder in my drive that these files need to go to. How to I point them to be saved in a specified folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A  few issues already solved in comments but I didn't see the biggest one at first : your main function is actually onFormSubmit but it is "hidden" in a myFunction function ...

please rewrite it like below and setup your trigger to run onFormSubmit as the main function now has a different name...

```
var docTemplate = "1pKwW-RcjaVV8xmm00hWDx1u2QxzQwaSjPJwVY2ux2nI";
var docName = "Form"; 
var full_name = "Form"; // you can keep these declarations as global variables

function onFormSubmit(e) { // this is the real function starting point
  var Assign_To_1 = e.value[2];
  var Assign_To_2 = e.value[3];
  var Timestamp = e.values[0];
  var Date_Of_Request = e.value[1];
  var Requested_By = e.value[7];
  var Principal_Approval = e.value[5];
  var Urgency = e.value[4];
  var Building_Room_Number = e.value[10];
  var Description_of_Work_To_Be_Done = e.value[6];
  var Parts_Needed = e.value[8];
  var Parts_In_Stock = e.value[9];
  var Invoice_Number = e.value[10];
  var Completed_Signature = e.value[22];
  var Incomplete_Signature = e.value[23];
  var On_Hold_Signature = e.value[24];
  var Estimated_Hours = e.value[14];
  var Number_Of_Employees_To_Complete = e.value[18];
  var Budget = e.value[11];
  var Follow_Up = e.value[16];
  var Overtime = e.value[15];
  var copyId = DocsList.getFileById(docTemplate)
  .makeCopy(docName+' for '+full_name)
  .getId();
  var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);
  var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();
  copyBody.replaceText('KeyAssignedTo1',Assign_To_1);
  copyBody.replaceText('KeyAssignedTo2',Assign_To_2);
  copyBody.replaceText('KeyTimestamp',Timestamp);
  copyBody.replaceText('KeyDateOfRequest',Date_Of_Request);
  copyBody.replaceText('KeyRequestedBy',Requested_By); 
  copyBody.replaceText('KeyPrincipalApproval',Principal_Approval);
  copyBody.replaceText('KeyUrgency',Urgency);
  copyBody.replaceText('KeyBuildingRoomNumber',Building_Room_Number);
  copyBody.replaceText('KeyDescriptionofWorkToBeDone',Description_of_Work_To_Be_Done);
  copyBody.replaceText('KeyPartsNeeded', Parts_Needed);
  copyBody.replaceText('KeyPartsInStock', Parts_In_Stock);
  copyBody.replaceText('KeyInvoiceNumber', Invoice_Number);
  copyBody.replaceText('KeyCompletedSignature', Completed_Signature);
  copyBody.replaceText('KeyIncompleteSignature', Incomplete_Signature);
  copyBody.replaceText('KeyOnHoldSignature', On_Hold_Signature);
  copyBody.replaceText('KeyEstimatedHours', Estimated_Hours);
  copyBody.replaceText('KeyNumberOfEmployeesToComplete', Number_Of_Employees_To_Complete);
  copyBody.replaceText('KeyBudget', Budget);
  copyBody.replaceText('KeyFoolowUp', Follow_Up);
  copyBody.replaceText('KeyOvertime', Overtime);
  copyDoc.saveAndClose();
  var pdf = DocsList.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf");
  var doc = DocsList.getFileById(copyId);
  var folders = doc.getParents();
  var newFolder=DocsList.getFolder(WorkOrderForms);
  doc.addToFolder(WorkOrderForms);
  var docParentFolder=folders[0];
  doc.removeFromFolder(docParentFolder);
}
```